# docker run [9] System error: exec format error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created Dockerfile to build my image called aii.

```
FROM docker.io/centos:latest

#Set parameters
ENV BinDir /usr/local/bin
ENV RunFile start-aii.sh

ADD ${RunFile} ${BinDir}
#Some other stuff
...

CMD ${RunFile}
```

When I run the image with the following command:

```
docker run -it -v <some-volume-mapping> aii
```

it's works great (default operation of running CMD command of start-aii.sh).
Now, if I try to override this default behavior and to run the image with the same script implicitly (and add another arg) I'm getting the following error:

```
docker run -it -v <some-volume-mapping> aii start-aii.sh kafka
exec format error
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container b3f4f3bde04d862eb8bc619ea55b7061ce78ace8f1984a12f6ec681877d7d926: [9] System error: exec format error.
```

I also tried: only script (without argument)

```
docker run -it -v <some-volume-mapping> aii start-aii.sh
```

and full path to script

```
docker run -it -v <some-volume-mapping> aii /usr/local/bin/start-aii.sh
```

but the same error appear.

Another info:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2488a4dd7014        aii                 "start-aii.sh kafka"     3 seconds ago       Created                                 tiny_payne
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Had the same issue, fixed it by adding `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the file instead of having other comments.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the tip ;-)

Comment: Do we need to include `#!/bin/sh` at the top of `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 8):

Try to start bash before using your script, and use the `--rm` flag in order to destroy the instance once the job is ended, like that :

```
docker run -it --rm -v <some-volume-mapping> aii /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/start-aii.sh
```

Comment: thanks for the --rm tip, I didn't know that.. I'm checking about the bash issue, I'll update soon

Answer (score 0):

If you created the file start-aii.sh in the Windows editor. After that, this file was added to the docker image. You should check this file in a Linux editor, e.g. nano. In my case there were non-printable characters at the beginning of the file. I removed them and my script ran successfully.